# Get multiple table items at the same time in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

In indexedDB I create one database with multiple dynamic objectstore 
from where I can get items from single table but when try to get all data from all tables using loop it showing only last table data with error message objectStore is not specified for previous table.There might be have any easy solution only i cant get it due to new with indexedDB.
Below is my function :

```
function displayData(store) {

    for(i = 0; i < TotalModule; i++) {
    ModuleCode= $("#MC_"+i).val();
     storeName = 'tableName_'+ModuleCode;
     DbStoreName .push(storeName );
    }
   DbStore = "'" + DbStoreName .join("','") + "'";

   if (typeof DbStore == 'undefined')

     tx = db.transaction(DbStore, 'readwrite');  //['tab1','tab2','tab3']

        $.each(DbStoreName , function(i) {
            STORE_NAME = DbStoreName [i];
            var ob = 'ob'+i;
            ob = tx.objectStore(STORE_NAME);
      });

}
```

[view Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaTBY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to call an asynchronous function within a synchronous for loop. Before using indexedDB, you should be very familiar with writing asynchronous Javascript.

That said, try something like the following pseudocode. I've chosen to use promises.

```
function load_store(store) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var request = store.getAll();
    request.onsuccess = () => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
  });
}

function load_stores(db, names) {
  var tx = db.transaction(names, 'readonly');
  var stores = names.map((name) => tx.objectStore(name));
  var load_store_promises = stores.map(load_store);
  return Promise.all(load_store_promises);
}

function displayData() {
  var names = ...;
  var db ...;
  load_stores(db, names).then(function(array_of_arrays) {
    console.log('data:', array_of_arrays);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('loading error', error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Great solution  It's  work perfect. Thank you so much .. @Josh